# Access domain:port instead of IP:port

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, cloudflare

I have the following in Ubuntu 12.04:

1. Daemon Python script listening port 3333.
2. Apache2 configured for domain name and port 80.
3. Iptables allowed anything.
4. CloudFlare as a frontend for domain (3333 port connections 100% goes directly to server)

mydomain.com:80 - works great and launch website.

IP:3333 - works great and connects to my daemon.

mydomain.com:3333 - doesn't work.

Why?

Tried to turn off CloudFlare, no result. Because they don't deal with 3333 port: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since :3333 port is bound by Daemon Python script, then that script is responsible for parsing HTTP headers, you should look into that script and find why the hostname in header causes the problem. Might be the domain hostname is not resolvable to IP internally, or resolves to incorrect IP, f.e. by rules in /etc/hosts

Comment: Thank you! It was an CloudFlare issue. DNS pointed to their cloud IP and /etc/hosts had wrong config.

Comment: good. my pleasure  :)

Answer (score 0):

if you pass your domain through cloudflare by clicking cloud-image, your port will be only available like this :

For requests made via HTTP (all domains on CloudFlare):

80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095

For requests made via HTTPS (only domains subscribed to Pro, Business, or Enterprise):

443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443

my solution is create one sub-domain that not pass through cloudflare for any instance like ssh, python etc.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-